# Turn on NumLock on startup in Linux Mint in the Login window

Tags: linux-mint, login, keyboard, numlock

**Situation:**

When I turn on my Linux Mint 20/19/18/17 Cinnamon the <kbd>NumLock</kbd> is Off in the Login window.

**Objective:**

Turn on NumLock automatically at startup in the Login window.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### For all versions of Linux Mint

You need to install a program needed for this purpose - `numlockx`; [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/numlockx.1.html):

```
sudo apt-get install numlockx
```

Choose if you wish to achieve the goal through [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) or [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) below.

---

### Linux Mint 20.x / 19.x (LightDM)

**[GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface)**; probably most convenient under normal operation:

Once `numlockx` is installed, the following menu item in Login Window -> Settings called:

> ```
> Activate numlock
> ```

becomes available; as you can see:

[image: Login Window Settings]

This will add the line:

> ```
> activate-numlock=true
> ```

to the following file:

```
/etc/lightdm/slick-greeter.conf
```

---

### Linux Mint 18.x / 17.x (MDM)

**[GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface)**; probably most convenient under normal operation:

Once `numlockx` is installed, the following menu item in Login Window -> Options called:

> ```
> Enable NumLock
> ```

becomes available; as you can see:

[image: Login Window Preferences]

As pointed out in [the other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322924/126755), this will add the following line to `/etc/mdm/mdm.conf`:

> ```
> EnableNumLock=true
> ```

---

**[CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface)**; suitable if you are setting other computers up through SSH, for instance:

Open a text editor you are skilled in with this file, e.g. [`nano`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) if unsure:

```
sudoedit /etc/mdm/Init/Default
```

Add these lines at the beginning of the file:

```sh
if [ -x /usr/bin/numlockx ]; then
    /usr/bin/numlockx on
fi
```

As pointed out by [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles), don't put `exec` in front of the command.

Answer (score 3):

When you install numlockx (mentioned by [vlastimil](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/126755/vlastimil) above) on Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon than the option is called **Activate numlock** located in **System Settings > Login Window > Settings**.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Works to me by just installing `numlockx` package.

I didn't have to add those lines.

I can enable NumLock on Login Screen, from the GUI: Login Window (Preferences) » Options.

I see that in `/etc/mdm/mdm.conf` a new entry has been added:

```
EnableNumLock=true
```

(My OS: Linux Mint 17.3 Mate 64-bit.)