# NumLock is off on start-up on Linux Mint 18.2

Tags: linux-mint, lightdm, numlock

I upgraded my OS to the latest version - Linux Mint 18.2 Sarah. After upgrading my NumLock is off. I changed my display manager from mdm to lightdm. [this method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275474/turn-on-numlock-on-startup-in-linux-mint) is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jaleks' answer was only almost right for me, but this finally worked (Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon, manually updated to LightDM (from LM 18.1)):

Install `sudo apt install numlockx`, after that, edit `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/90-slick-greeter.conf` file and add the following line at the end:

```
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

Answer (score 0):

try to edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`:

```
[Seat:*]
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

Just for reference: weird enough there is a whole ecosystem for numlock settings, depending on which display/window managers one uses, see e.g. the always great Arch wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Activating_Numlock_on_Bootup

Answer (score 0):

## On plain Ubuntu

First install the `numlockx` package:

```
$ sudo apt install numlockx
```

On plain Ubuntu, the LightDM directory in which to create the configuration file is named slightly differently:

```
$ cd /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
$ sudo touch 00-keyboard.conf
$ sudo nano 00-keyboard.conf
```

The following configuration worked for me:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

In this very configuration file, one can [**also define the keyboard layout**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/435228/39845) to be used during the LightDM login session.

Answer (score -1):

Mint 18.3 the setup for Numlockx has been added in the "login screen" option (within the "administration" menu)

cf : https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_sylvia_cinnamon_whatsnew.php